# maven assembly plugin do not set file attributes

Tags: maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I know this is a duplicate of [Maven assembly plugin not applying fileMode on unpacked dependencySet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380530/maven-assembly-plugin-not-applying-filemode-on-unpacked-dependencyset) but it's still unanswered.
My assembly is

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
<id>distribution</id>
<formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <fileMode>775</fileMode>
        <includes>
            <include>eu.els.inneo.tools:compare-files-shells</include>
        </includes>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <unpackOptions>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/**</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </unpackOptions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>jars</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <includes>
            <include>eu.els.inneo.tools:compare-files-xml</include>
            <include>eu.els.inneo.tools:compare-files-diff</include>
        </includes>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

**eu.els.inneo.tools:compare-files-shells** is a **jar** packaging the contains only shell files (bash and config files), and I want them to be runnable by everyone.

Building this tar.gz, shell files are 644.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Christophe

Comment: I've declared an issue : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-829

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven assembly plugin not applying fileMode on unpacked dependencySet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380530/maven-assembly-plugin-not-applying-filemode-on-unpacked-dependencyset)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-829

Solved in 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT